# Npm install not working its every slow ERR msg CODE 1

Tags: node.js, npm

npm install  not working unable install packages

tried reinstall, try some fix like  registry change  but no effect

is this the problem with node version or windows and it take to much time to give this error

````
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Git\myntraClone\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc
npm ERR!   Generating code
npm ERR!   Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation.
npm ERR!   All 1 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
npm ERR!   Finished generating code
npm ERR!   WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.vcxproj -> D:\Git\myntraClone\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.node
npm ERR!   address_sorting.c
npm ERR!   address_sorting_posix.c
npm ERR!   address_sorting_windows.c
npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc
npm ERR!   address_sorting.vcxproj -> D:\Git\myntraClone\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\libaddress_sorting.lib
npm ERR!   ares__close_sockets.c
npm ERR!   ares__get_hostent.c
npm ERR! D:\Git\myntraClone\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\xds\xds_load_balancer_api.cc(61,16): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch [D:\Git\myntraClone\node_modules\grpc\build\grpc.vcxproj]
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.8.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.8.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.1 found at "C:\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/node-v15.8.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/node-v15.8.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/win-arm64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 404 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/win-arm64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.8.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.8.31005.135) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python39\python.exe


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bskre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-18T13_54_19_553Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I had to update my project dependencies then it took around 1/2hr to install

Comment: Could you please anyone help. I am also facing the same issue.